# What is the difference between current_user.present and if user_signed_in?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Working on devise and was wondering what the difference are between

```
<% if current_user.present? %>
```

and

```
<% if user_signed_in? %>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there isn't really a difference.

Look at the meta-programmed implementation of [`user_signed_in?`](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/88724e10adaf9ffd1d8dbfbaadda2b9d40de756a/lib/devise/controllers/helpers.rb#L119):

```
def #{mapping}_signed_in?
  !!current_#{mapping}
end
```

When authenticating against a `User` model this resolves to:

```
def user_signed_in?
  !!current_user
end
```

Note: `!!current_user` returns `true` if `current_user` is `nil` or `false`. And that is exactly the same what [`present?`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_core_extensions.html#blank-questionmark-and-present-questionmark) does.